# Please explain the flow of program when using Tiles for displaying menu using spring

Tags: java, spring

I have to do some maintenance work on an existing spring project. I am new to spring and am finding it difficult to understand the flow of the program.It is a web application having various menus in the home page.

There is no main class in the project.

From my research, I understood that it uses Tiles feature of spring.

Where does the control flow go first? Can anyone please explain in simple terms the overall flow of a spring application? Any help will be appreciated as I am completely at sea even after going through many forums and tutorials.

Comment: Do you have problems understanding the overall request dispatch or just the view rendering phase? Check this very cool diagram for `DispatcherServlet`'s request handling phases - http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?21639-Spring-MVC-Request-Lifecycle-Diagram

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud:

- In your Spring configurations, there should be a bean `TilesConfigurer`. Depending on the version of Spring, it could be Java code or an XML configuration.
- From bean properties, you should be able to find out the location of Tiles template/layout definitions; examples could be `tiles-defs.xml` or `tiles.xml` or it can even be a properties file.
- Looking at Tiles layout should guide you through how the flow is designed using the framework. In the layout definition, you find "view name"s that are bound to specific JSP/HTML resources.
- Remember that the "view name" in Apache Tiles is *the string value* returned from a Spring controller method.

For instance:

```
public String controllerMethod(...) {
  // controller logic
  return "myView";
}
```

in which "myView" is the name of the view which appears in tiles definition.

I believe this should get you started. There are [many examples](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-tiles-integration-1.html) if you search for it!